# how to start xampp in fedora?

Tags: linux, unix

i am installing xampp in fedora and starting it raise an error can any body tell why it is coming

```
[root@localhost naveen]# sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: /opt/lampp/bin/my_print_defaults: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP: /opt/lampp/lampp: /opt/lampp/sbin/proftpd: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Error 126! Couln't start ProFTPD!
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

Comment: Have you installed another apache server ?
Try sudo ps -u apache

Comment: no i am not install another apache

Answer (score 0):

> XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.

```
# lsof -i :80
# netstat --inet -nlp | grep :80
```

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

It sounds like you installed 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS. Install 32-bit compatibility library and try again:

```
# yum install glibc.i686
```